# Optional spaces and multiple alternatives in wl-pprint-extras

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

Is there a good/accepted way to get more than two alternative layouts, specifically in a way which supports optional spaces?

In particular, I might want to print a list in one of three ways:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[1,2,3,4,5]

[ 1
, 2
, 3
, 4
, 5
]
```

in that order of preference.

Comment: The underlying `Doc` has a `Union` constructor which tries one alternative, and, if it doesn't fit across the page, tries a second one. The only way it is exposed is via `group x = Union (flatten x) x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try one alternatives before another with `group` and `flatAlt`.

```
(<|>) :: Doc e -> Doc e -> Doc e
a <|> b = group $ flatAlt b a

infixl 5 <|>
```

We'll define your three examples.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.PrettyPrint.Free
import System.IO

items = map char ['1'..'5']

widest = brackets . hcat . punctuate ", " $ items
wide   = brackets . hcat . punctuate ","  $ items
skinny = brackets . hcat . punctuate "," . map (\x -> " " <> x <> linebreak) $ items
```

The widest of these that fits on the screen, `widestFits`, can be defined in terms of `<|>` which we defined above.

```
widestFits = widest <|> wide <|> skinny
```

We will try pretty printing these on three documents, one wide enough to hold the `widest` example, one only wide enough to hold the `wide` example, and one that can't hold either.

```
main = do
    displayIO stdout $ renderPretty 1.0 15 widestFits
    putStrLn ""
    displayIO stdout $ renderPretty 1.0 14 widestFits   
    putStrLn "" 
    displayIO stdout $ renderPretty 1.0 10 widestFits
    putStrLn "
```

This results in the desired output.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
[ 1
, 2
, 3
, 4
, 5
]
```