# Stick with 2 layouts only when pretty printing

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm pretty-printing a C++ method declaration and I want arguments list to be rendered in a compact form if it fits the line:

```
void method(MyLongClassName& instance, const MyClass& c);
```

or to be formatted in columns if it doesn't:

```
void method(      MyLongClassName& instance,
            const MyClass&         c,
                  int              counter);
```

all other layouts I want to eliminate from consideration.
It seems to be simple neither with [wl-pprint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint) nor with [pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty), if not hacking the sources.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you doing this? Are you reading the source code from a file and trying to print it in your format? Or do you just have hard-coded strings you are trying to format?

Comment: Check the length of your possible output, if it fits the line, print it, otherwise, create yourself a board (2d sequence or else), fill each cell of it (column0 might be return type, column1 the name + (, column2 `const`, etc.), find the max width for each column, iterate on each row printing white space where needed according to the column's max width, done.

Comment: @JustinWood: it should be general enough for any correct method definition, so no hard-coding

Comment: @gxtaillon: I'm very reluctant doing this myself, as this is exactly what we need pretty-printing libraries for. :) Another drawback is that to check the length of the output I need to render the preceding method declaration, so basically render everything twice.

Comment: @AdelNick I don't think you need to render everything twice, use the board to find out the lengths then use `pretty`'s `($$)` and `nest` with the column widths it gave you. You could probably commit that to pretty afterwards as a table prettyfier.

Comment: Yes I want a table prettifier sometimes (for matrices), it would be a useful addition to wl-pprint. --- No, I would never use it for the OP's purpose. I think source code indentation should not depend on (lengths of) names of identifiers (in this case, method names). Because if you change one name, you need to reformat a lot. Instead, indent/outdent by a fixed amount for each logical nesting level.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42: this is the whole idea of what I'm trying to achieve: reformat code automatically for me if I change something :) For a table prettifier you might want to look at Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes-0.1.1/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Boxes.html) for my purposes it has some drawbacks

Comment: @gxtaillon: No doubt, I can implement it myself. I wonder if there is such functionality in existing pretty printing libraries

Comment: @AdelNick: didn't know about boxes package. What drawbacks? Render into the box, then `vcat . map text . lines` or something`?

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42: the problem is not that I don't know how to align the argument list in columns. The problem is that I want a pretty printing library to choose between only two layouts: aligned in columns and the compact one. Please note, that the aligned layout cannot just be flattened in one line to get the compact layout, as it contains redundant spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to a more general problem how to choose a layout that fits to a single line or, if none, use a substitute can be found here: [Optional spaces and multiple alternatives in wl-pprint-extras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440998/890355)